# What resolution would achieve a 1:1 pixel ratio while using "wallpaper motion effect" on a Quad HD screen?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, wallpaper, samsung-galaxy-s7

I like the "Wallpaper Motion Effect" that is available in Android Marshmallow, but I find that using it with a properly sized 1440x2560 image results in the image being zoomed-in somewhat, which means the image is no longer displayed at a 1:1 pixel-perfect ratio.

What resolution would I need to create an image at in order to have a 1:1 pixel ratio once the image has been zoomed-in by the use of this feature?

Comment: Have you tried doubling the horizontal pixel amount? 2880x2560 might be working for you :) [see here for example pictures](https://www.google.de/search?q=2880x2560&num=30&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSoPqyx_zNAhWE_iwKHR4ECYAQ_AUICCgB&biw=1280&bih=901)

Comment: I don't think doubling is right because it doesn't zoom in that much. It's a subtle effect. The horizontal axis isn't only affected, the picture will have to gain vertical pixels as well; how many pixels is the mystery.

Comment: alright - though 2880x2560 seems to work allright with my LG G4. Samsung may have implemented its own standard for this :P